# array references in a vba loop?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, loops, variables

OK... second attempt at posting this. Trying to make my question make sense please be patient with me, I am new at all of this.

The code below words PERFECTLY. It reads from the Range in column A and give me a string of all the cells where the searched numbers occur.

My only issue is its obviously not condensed at all. I have tried loops and arrays for the references but i can't seem to get it work. i would prefer something along the lines of reference(1-10) in stead of ref1, ref2, ref3. i had them all ref(i) with a loop around the whole macro but i ended up getting no results and an endless loop. any help to make this more streamlined would be appreciated. i have the full code if that will help anyone. I only put three iterations of the code it simply continues on with more references. up to 9

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindAircraftHourly()

Dim Findarray() As Integer 'the array to put numbers in
Dim count1, count2, count3, count4, count5, count6, count7, count8, count9 As Integer 'this will count the number of records you will need for your array
Dim n1, n2, n3, n4, n5, n6, n7, n8, n9 As Integer 'this will be what gets you through your For loops
Dim Searchvalue1, Searchvalue2, Searchvalue3, Searchvalue4, Searchvalue5, Searchvalue6, Searchvalue7, Searchvalue8, Searchvalue9 As Integer 'this is the number to look for
Dim Foundstring1, Foundstring2, foundstring3, foundstring4, foundstring5, foundstring6, foundstring7, Foundstring8, Foundstring9 As String 'this will build where the numbers are found
Dim k1 As Integer
Dim data As Worksheet

Set data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data")

If Cells(1, 3) <> "" Then 'test to make sure it has something to look for
    Searchvalue1 = Cells(1, 3) * 1 'E18 is the search value for the function this converts it to number and not text
Else
    MsgBox "No input found!", vbCritical 'if blank, give a warning and quit
    GoTo the_end
End If

k1 = data.Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Row

count1 = 0 'always initialize your variables
For n1 = 1 To k1 'count through all the rows to find the end of the list
If Cells(n1, 1) <> "" Then 'is the cell blank or not?
    count1 = count1 + 1 'if not blank, then increase the count
    Else
        Exit For 'if it's blank, stop looking and counting
End If
Next n1

ReDim Findarray1(0 To count1 - 1) As Integer 'array indexes start at 0, so subtract 1 to get the right number of elements

For n1 = 0 To UBound(Findarray1) 'go from the first element to the last of the array
Findarray1(n1) = Cells(n1 + 1, 1) 'load the array change the last number in the cells box to change where to start looking
Next n1

For n1 = 0 To UBound(Findarray1)
If Findarray1(n1) = Searchvalue1 Then
    If Foundstring1 = "" Then 'if this is the first time found, create the string
        Foundstring1 = n1 + 1
        Else
            Foundstring1 = Foundstring1 & ", " & n1 + 1 'if this is the second time the number is found, add a comma and continue to build the string.
    End If
End If
Next n1

If Foundstring1 = "" Then
MsgBox "Not found", vbCritical 'msgbox nothing was found
Else
    Cells(1, 4) = Foundstring1 'output the string to a certain cell
End If

'-----------------------------------------------------------------------    
If Cells(2, 3) <> "" Then 'test to make sure it has something to look for
    Searchvalue2 = Cells(2, 3) * 1 'E18 is the search value for the function this converts it to number and not text
    Else
    MsgBox "No input found!", vbCritical 'if blank, give a warning and quit
    GoTo the_end
End If

k1 = data.Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Row

count2 = 0 'always initialize your variables
For n2 = 1 To k1 'count through all the rows to find the end of the list
    If Cells(n2, 1) <> "" Then 'is the cell blank or not?
        count2 = count2 + 1 'if not blank, then increase the count
        Else
        Exit For 'if it's blank, stop looking and counting
    End If
Next n2

ReDim FindArray2(0 To count2 - 1) As Integer 'array indexes start at 0, so subtract 1 to get the right number of elements

For n2 = 0 To UBound(FindArray2) 'go from the first element to the last of the array
    FindArray2(n2) = Cells(n2 + 1, 1) 'load the array change the last number in the cells box to change where to start looking
Next n2

For n2 = 0 To UBound(FindArray2)
    If FindArray2(n2) = Searchvalue2 Then
    If Foundstring2 = "" Then 'if this is the first time found, create the string
        Foundstring2 = n2 + 1
        Else
            Foundstring2 = Foundstring2 & ", " & n2 + 1 'if this is the second time the number is found, add a comma and continue to build the string.
        End If
    End If
Next n2

If Foundstring2 = "" Then
MsgBox "Not found", vbCritical 'msgbox nothing was found
Else
    Cells(2, 4) = Foundstring2 'output the string to a certain cell
End If
'-----------------------------------------------------------
If Cells(3, 3) <> "" Then 'test to make sure it has something to look for
Searchvalue3 = Cells(3, 3) * 1 'E18 is the search value for the function this converts it to number and not text
Else
    MsgBox "No input found!", vbCritical 'if blank, give a warning and quit
    GoTo the_end
End If

k1 = data.Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Row

count3 = 0 'always initialize your variables
For n3 = 1 To k1 'count through all the rows to find the end of the list
    If Cells(n3, 1) <> "" Then 'is the cell blank or not?
    count3 = count3 + 1 'if not blank, then increase the count
        Else
            Exit For 'if it's blank, stop looking and counting
    End If
Next n3

ReDim FindArray3(0 To count3 - 1) As Integer 'array indexes start at 0, so subtract 1 to get the right number of elements

For n3 = 0 To UBound(FindArray3) 'go from the first element to the last of the array
    FindArray3(n3) = Cells(n3 + 1, 1) 'load the array change the last number in the cells box to change where to start looking
Next n3

For n3 = 0 To UBound(FindArray3)
    If FindArray3(n3) = Searchvalue3 Then
        If foundstring3 = "" Then 'if this is the first time found, create the string
            foundstring3 = n3 + 1
            Else
                foundstring3 = foundstring3 & ", " & n3 + 1 'if this is the second time the number is found, add a comma and continue to build the string.
        End If
    End If
Next n3

If foundstring3 = "" Then
MsgBox "Not found", vbCritical 'msgbox nothing was found
Else
    Cells(3, 4) = foundstring3 'output the string to a certain cell
End If
the_end: 'end marker

End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question further to make it absolutely clear what your code does, without us having to read the actual code and work it out. Every sentence in your question should be self explanatory. For instance, you say *My only issue is its obviously not condensed at all. * **What** is obviously not condensed?

Comment: Quick note: 

    Dim count1, count2, count3...count9 As Integer 

doesn't declare them all as integers. It declares them all as Variant types except for count9 which is an Integer.

But to your main point, if I understand this correctly, you have column A populated with values, column C populated with search values you want found in Col A, and, if those values are found, you want the row numbers for those values listed in Col D next to the search value. Is that correct?

Comment: I'll attempt to answer one question at a time. Bottom line is the code works and does what i need it to do. search a series (or array) of serial numbers through a mixed worksheet and returns a string of numbers (which is the rows the respective serial numbers are stored in) i later use these strings to copy the correlating rows into other sheets. I needed a way to do all the S/N's and not one at a time. So i had to copy the code 9 times, and create 9 "versions" of the variables. I was hoping to get some assistance with some way to condense the variables.

Comment: instead of having n1, n2, n3, ect. is there a way to make and array/loop function so my variables are all var(i), or count(i), or whatever the name is with a revolving number at the end. First pass through all the variables are count(1), findstring(1), ect... second time through all the variables are count(2), findstring (2) and so on. i tried loops and arrays but it either ended up with no results or stuck in a seemingly endless loop (which still yielded no results). I didn't get any errors when i tried this, just didn't get what i needed. Thank you in advance for you help and your patience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your data looks like, but I would suggest a few things:

```
'finds the absolute last row with data in it // ignores empty cells
k1 = data.UsedRange.Rows.Count

count1 = 0
For n1 = 1 To k1
    'here's a built-in function to help you check empty cells.

    'if you're going to reference ranges, then you need to define on which worksheet
    'you're referencing the ranges from. if you work with multiple worksheets, you
    'can't simply use Cells(x,y); you need to use worksheet.Cells(x,y).

    'If you want to access a cell's value, then you use the .Value property.
    If Not IsEmpty(data.Cells(n1, 1).Value) Then
        count1 = count1 + 1
        Else
            Exit For
    End If
Next n1
```

I highly suggest using Collections instead of arrays because, for me, they're far easier to deal-with than arrays. They also start their indices at 1, so if you have a collection of 10 items, you count 1 through 10 instead of 0 through 9.

Defining and setting Collections:

```
Dim FindArray As New Collection
```

Or

```
Dim FindArray As Collection
Set FindArray = New Collection
```

Iterating over a collection:

```
Dim v As Variant
Dim sample As Double

For Each v In FindArray
    'i personally like to recast all variant types to
    'the intended data type
    sample = v

    'do your thing here
Next
```

Or

```
For i = 0 To FindArray.Count
    'do your other thing here
Next
```

Here's my attempt at making your code cleaner; hope it helps!
PS: All my castings are based on assumptions, so change them to whatever type you were intending.

Main:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim data As Worksheet
Dim n As Long
Dim SearchValue As Double
Dim Found As String
Dim output As New Collection
Dim FindArray As Collection
Dim count As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long

Set wb = Excel.Application.ThisWorkbook
Set data = wb.Worksheets("data")

k = data.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'find the last row before an empty record appears
For n = 1 To k
    If Not IsEmpty(data.Cells(n, 1).Value) Then
        count = n
    ElseIf IsEmpty(data.Cells(n ,1).Value) Then
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'do the thing 9 times
For n = 1 To 9
    If Not IsEmpty(data.Cells(n, 3).Value) Then 
        'cast the cell value to double and assign it to searchvalue
        SearchValue = CDbl(data.Cells(n, 3).Value)
    'i prefer to be extremely specific, but that's just me
    Elseif IsEmpty(data.Cells(n, 3).Value) Then
        MsgBox "No input found!", vbCritical 
        GoTo the_end
    End If

    'reset findarray to an empty collection
    Set FindArray = New Collection
    For i = 1 To count
        'load your collection with the sample values casted to doubles
        FindArray.Add CDbl(data.Cells(i, 1).Value)
    Next

    j = 1
    Found = ""
    For i = 1 To FindArray.Count
        If FindArray(i) = SearchValue Then
            If j = 1 Then
                Found = i
            ElseIf j > 1 Then
                'im not sure what you're trying to accomplish with this line,
                'so im just going to leave it as is and adjust it for my solution
                'so it gives you the same output
                Found = n & ", " & i
            End If
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next

    If Found = "" Then
        MsgBox "Not found", vbCritical
    Else
        output.Add Found
    End If

    'i like to always just set the collection to nothing before a new iteration
    Set FindArray = Nothing
Next

'dump all results in column 4
For i = 1 To output.Count
    data.Cells(i, 4).Value = output(i)
Next

'garbage collection
Set FindArray = Nothing
Set output = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
Set data = Nothing

the_end:
    Exit Sub
```

I'm not entirely sure if this attempt at a solution will work for you, but I hope it's helpful in any way. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Col A populated with values, Col C populated with search values to be found in Col A, Col D is where the row numbers of each value in Col C can be found.

The number of values in Col A and Col C are essentially limited only by the number of rows in your spreadsheet with no changes required to the code.

If you have not added a Dictionary reference, click on [Tools] at the top of the screen, click on [References...], scroll way down until you find [Microsoft Scripting Runtime], click the check mark next to that, then click [OK].

```
Sub FindAircraftHourly()
Dim dnySource As New Scripting.Dictionary
Dim strCellValue As String
Dim i0 As Long
With ActiveSheet
    For i0 = 2 To .Rows.Count 'This starts at row 2 and goes to the end of the list. I'm assuming row 1 has a heading of some sort.
        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i0, 1)) Then 'If the cell in col A of that row has a value, add that value to the dictionary as the key and the row number(s) as the items(s).
            strCellValue = .Cells(i0, 1).Value
            dnySource(strCellValue) = dnySource(strCellValue) & i0 & ", "
        Else
            Exit For 'Once you hit an empty cell, stop building the dictionary.
        End If
    Next i0

    For i0 = 2 To .Rows.Count
        If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(i0, 3)) Then 'If the cell in col C has a value then look through the dictionary to see if you have a list of row numbers to display.
            strCellValue = .Cells(i0, 3).Value
            If dnySource.Exists(strCellValue) Then 'If there is a list of row numbers for that value, display them in col D.
                .Cells(i0, 4).Value = Left$(dnySource(strCellValue), Len(dnySource(strCellValue)) - 2) 'The - 2 here chops off the extra ", " at the end
            Else 'Otherwise, indicate that the value in col C doesn't exist in col A.
                .Cells(i0, 4).Value = "Value Not Found"
            End If
        Else
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i0
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt to solve your problem.
For questions just ask.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FindAircraftHourly()

Dim data As Worksheet
Dim searchrange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim findarray() As String
Dim searcharray() As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")      'the sheet your working on

Const maxinputvals As Integer = 3   'The number of search values you want to be looking for
ReDim searcharray(1 To maxinputvals) As Integer   'VBA doesn't need to start at 0
ReDim findarray(1 To maxinputvals) As String    'VBA doesn't need to start at 0

i = 0 'not needed but always nice to make sure
Do
    i = i + 1       'add 1 to the count-var
    If i > maxinputvals Then Exit Do    'if the count-var si bigger than max number of searchvalues quit the loop
    If data.Cells(i, 3) <> "" Then  'check if cells is not empty
        searcharray(i) = data.Cells(i, 3).Value     'safe the searchvalue
    Else
        MsgBox "Searchvalue #" & i & " is missing."     'exit the sub if a searchvalue is missing
        Exit Sub
    End If
Loop

Set searchrange = data.Range("A1:A5000")

For Each cell In searchrange        'go through the whole range
    If cell.Value <> "" Then        'check is cell is empty
        For i = 1 To maxinputvals   'if not, check if match with one of the searchvals
            If cell.Value = searcharray(i) Then
                findarray(i) = findarray(i) & ", " & cell.Row     'append your findarray string
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        Exit For        'if cell is empty exit the loop
    End If
Next cell

For i = 1 To maxinputvals
    findarray(i) = Mid(findarray(i), 3)     'delete the first ", "
    data.Cells(i, 4) = findarray(i)         'output the findstring
Next i

End Sub
```